# C++ convert digits to words

Tags: c++, digits

I think my logic is correct but the while loops infinitely, outputting zero. Here is my code:

```
int currentMSD, currentNum = num;
if (currentNum >= 0 && currentNum < 100) {
    currentMSD = 10;
} else if (currentNum >= 100 && currentNum < 1000) {
    b1 = b * msd;
    b2 = num3 - b1;
    num3 = b2;
    switch(b) {
        case 1:
            cout << "one ";
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << "two ";
            cout << "five ";
            break;
        case 6:
            cout << "six ";
            break;
        case 9:
            cout << "nine ";
            break;
        case 0:
            cout << "zero ";
          break;
        }
    }
    cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Here's a hint: run through your code with num3 = 1

Comment: You should add an `else` block to `getMSD()` (with an `assert(false);` if nothing else) so that you can actually detect when an invalid range occurs instead of returning an uninitialized value.  Similarly, a `default:` should be added to the `switch` in `getWords()` just in case the calculations don't work the way you expect and you end up with a value that isn't from 0 to 9.

Comment: Perhaps looking at some [existing code](http://www8.cs.umu.se/~isak/snippets/fmtmoney.c) could provide some inspiration/guidance.

Comment: is this homework?  If so, add the homework tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getMSD()` function is faulty. replace it with this new one

```
int getMSD(int num) {

int currentMSD = 1, currentNum = num;

if (currentNum >= 10 && currentNum < 100)
{
    currentMSD = 10;
}
else if (currentNum >= 100 && currentNum < 1000)
{
    currentMSD = 100;
}
else if (currentNum >= 1000 && currentNum < 10000)
{
    currentMSD = 1000;
}
return currentMSD;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What type of output are you expecting for something like 250?  "two five zero"?

Here's a quick example:

```
#include <iostream>

const char* nums[] = {"zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", 
                      "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"};

void getMSD(unsigned int num)
{
    unsigned int remainder = num % 10;
    unsigned int result = num / 10;

    if(result > 0)
        getMSD(result);

    std::cout << nums[remainder] << " ";
}

int main()
{
    getMSD(125); //prints "one two five"

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `getMSD` function, you need a check for the ones digit:

```
int getMSD(int num) {
    int currentMSD, currentNum = num;

    if (currentNum < 10) {
        currentMSD = 1;
    } else if (currentNum >= 10 && currentNum < 100) {
        currentMSD = 10;
    } else if (currentNum >= 100 && currentNum < 1000) {
        currentMSD = 100;
    } else if (currentNum >= 1000 && currentNum < 10000) {
        currentMSD = 1000;
    }
    return currentMSD;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are not checking for numbers from 1 - 9 in 'getMsd' function. However I would not recommend you to use this logic since it is not scalable. What I mean is you cant use this code to with 6 digits number

Answer (score 0):

You have done a logical mistake. According to your logic you have 250 as input,

```
msd = 100 , then b = 250/100 = 2.5 = 2 which should output 'two'
b1 = msd * b = 100 * 2 = 200
b2 = num - b1 = 250 - 200 = 50
num = b2 = 50
repeat
msd = 10, then b = 50/10 = 5 which should then output 'five'
b1 = msd * b = 50
b2 = num - b1 = 50 - 50 = 0
```

This logic work fine if the input is 250 but when your input will be 205 It will never print "zero" because when you subtract `num - b1` `205-200` you will get 5.

As far as your program concern, you are misusing `while` condition  because according to your condition `while (num3 > 0)` this condition will never print last digit.

Hope you get me point. :)

Answer (score 0):

Do more control (beautify):

```
int getMSD(const int& num) {
   int currentMSD = 1;
   const int N = 3;  
   for(int j = 1, i = 1; j != N; ++j, i * 10) {
      if(num >= 10 * i && num < 100 * i) {
          currentMSD = 10 * i;
       }
   }          
   return currentMSD;
}
```